# Call to undefined function ecrypt()

Tags: function, codeigniter, undefined, fatal-error

ERROR:Fatal error: Call to undefined function ecrypt()

code all works fine without the ecrypt function call in the anchor. I want to secure it from code injection. why am i getting the above error?

view:

```
<?php
echo anchor("resetPasswordController/delete_news/".ecrypt($content1['id']),      
'<i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i>Delete','id="actions"', array
('onClick' => "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"));?>
```

controller:

```
function delete_news() {
   $this->load->library('encrypt');
   $this->load->model('users_model');
   //var_dump($product_id);die();
   $ls_id= $this->decrypt($this->uri->segment(3));
   $result = $this->users_model->get_id($ls_id);
   $this->users_model->delete($ls_id);
   $this->db->trans_complete();

    $message2 = "News has been deleted successfully";
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message2');     </script>";

    $this->manage_news();
}



// Encryption function starts 
function ecrypt($str)
{ 
    $result ="";
    $key = "snowtogsbydigitechsoftwaresolutionsabcxyzdfvdfd";
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++) 
    {
        $char = substr($str, $i, 1);
        $keychar = substr($key, ($i % strlen($key))-1, 1);
        $char = chr(ord($char)+ord($keychar));
        $result.=$char;
    }
    return base64_encode($result);
}    
    // Encryption function end



    // This code use for id decrypt 

function decrypt($str)
{
    $str = base64_decode($str);
    $result = '';
    $key = "snowtogsbydigitechsoftwaresolutionsabcxyzdfvdfd";
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($str); $i++) 
    {
        $char = substr($str, $i, 1);
        $keychar = substr($key, ($i % strlen($key))-1, 1);
        $char = chr(ord($char)-ord($keychar));
        $result.=$char;
    }
    return $result;
}
// decryption function end
```

model:

```
function delete($id){
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete('news');
    }
function get_id($id){
        $this->db->where('id',$id);     
        $query = $this->db->get('news');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: Instead of placing the encrypt function in your controller, place it in a helper file. It will then work as you're trying to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your views:

```
    <?php
$CI = & get_instance();
    echo anchor("resetPasswordController/delete_news/".$CI->ecrypt($content1['id']),      
    '<i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i>Delete','id="actions"', array
    ('onClick' => "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"));?>
```

**Update solution:**
Base64 return a string that have = at the last, this may cause problem so you can replace it

```
 function ecrypt($str)
{ 
    $result ="";
    $key = "snowtogsbydigitechsoftwaresolutionsabcxyzdfvdfd";
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++) 
    {
        $char = substr($str, $i, 1);
        $keychar = substr($key, ($i % strlen($key))-1, 1);
        $char = chr(ord($char)+ord($keychar));
        $result.=$char;

    }
    $data = base64_encode($result);
    $data = str_replace(array('='),array('.'),$data);
return $data

}
```

Similarly replace '.' with = in decrypt function

Comment: i tried that but got -> The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.  i edited config.php to allow ->  'a-z 0-9~%.:&_\-'; but it gives the above error

Comment: its working now thanks. i changed the config to -> $config['permitted_uri_chars'] =  '+=a-z 0-9?~%.,:_\-';